# How to stack multiple 2D numpy arrays in a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, audio, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am extracting features from Audio clips. In doing so for 1 clip a matrix of `20x2` dimension is obtained. I have around `1000` of such clips. I want to store all the data in 1 numpy array of dimension `20x2x1000`. Please suggest a method for the same.

Comment: `np.array([list of clips])` will give you a (1000,20,2) array.  You could swap axes on that.  Or use `np.stack([list of clips], axis=2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is `np.stack`. It's used to stack multiple NumPy arrays along a new axis.

```
import numpy as np

# Generate 1000 features
original_features = [np.random.rand(20, 2) for i in range(1000)]

# Stack them into one array
stacked_features = np.stack(original_features, axis=2)
assert stacked_features.shape == (20, 2, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient function for this and that is [numpy.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html). Below is a snippet of code for depth stacking of arrays:

```
# whatever the number of arrays that you have
In [4]: tuple_of_arrs = tuple(np.random.randn(20, 2) for _ in range(10))

# stack each of the arrays along third axis
In [7]: depth_stacked = np.dstack(tuple_of_arrs)

In [8]: depth_stacked.shape
Out[8]: (20, 2, 10)
```